# Scanset behaviour in scanf in C

Tags: c, scanf

I tried to do some stuff with scanset in scanf but stuck somewhere.

when I write

```
char s1[250];
scanf("%[A-Z]",s1);

input : AHJHkiuy
Output: AHJH
```

and with this,

```
scanf("%[^\n]",s1);

input: abcd ABCD hie
output: abcd ABCD hie       /*that is reading white space also (till \n) */
```

Now My question is, if I give input as:

```
ABCDahaj ahajABCD ajak12347ab
```

and want the output as:

```
ABCDahaj ahajABCD ajak
```

then how should the format string be written? That is, how should this scanset be used?

Comment: Did you *carefully* read the output of `man scanf` on a Linux or Unix system??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could expand your example a little bit and achieve your goal.

```
scanf("%[A-Za-z ]", s1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do this would be:

```
scanf("%[^0-9]", s1); /* Scans everything until a digit */
```