# can someone help me with my c code

Tags: c

Hello so i am creating a program that reads from a file and outputs each category of the things in the text in sorted for example i want it to output like this :

```
Company name: air france Date of creation: 06281957 Flight number: AT6801 Incoming city: london Arrival city: paris Amount of fuel liters left: 380 Plane category: B777
```

this is the input :

```
air qatar06281957AT680londonmadrid380B777 turkish airlines05201933TK1298istanbulmadrid250A380 lufthansa01061953LH29frankfurtmadrid75B747 air canada06281957AT7245ammanmadrid120A320 turkish airlines05201933TK1266dohamadrid522A320 air france10071933AF123parismadrid105B777 -1
```

The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *inp,*outp;
    int i,j,c=0,l,c2=0,c3=0;int c4=0;int c5=0,c6=0,k,m,c7=0,flag=0;int c8=0,c9=0,c10=0,flag2=0,n,c11=0,c12=0,c13=0,c14=0,p=0,c15=0,c16=0,t,t1,t2,t3,t4,t5,t6,t7,s;
    char ultimate_array[600];char plane[100][6];char date[600][6];char nflight[600][6];char  destination[100][6];char fuel [100][6];char planetype [100][6];

    inp=fopen("input.txt","r");

    for(i=0;!feof(inp);i++)
    {
        fscanf(inp,"%c",&ultimate_array[i]);
    }

    s=strlen(ultimate_array);

    for(i=0;i<s;i++)
    {
        printf("%c",ultimate_array[i]);
    }

    printf("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n");
    for(t=0;t<6;t++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<200;j++)
        {
            c++;
            if(isdigit(ultimate_array[j]))
            {
                c3=c;
                while(c>=0)
                {
                    plane[t][c]=ultimate_array[j];
                    c--; j--;
                }
                break;
            }
        }

        for(k=0;k<200;k++)
        {
            c2++;
            if(isupper(ultimate_array[k]))
            {
                c5=c2; c2=c2-c3; c9=c2;
                while(c2>=0)
                {
                    date[t][c2]=ultimate_array[k];
                    k--; c2--;
                }
                break;
            }
        }

        for(l=c3;l<200;l++)
        {
            c4++;
            if(islower(ultimate_array[l]))
            {
                c4=c4+c3-c5;
                while(c4>=0)
                {
                    while(flag==0)
                    {
                        c8=c4; c6=c4+c5; flag=1;
                    }

                    nflight[t][c4]=ultimate_array[l];
                    c4--; l--;
                }
                break;
            }
        }

        c10=c9+c8;

        for(m=c6;m<200;m++)
        {
            c7++;
            if(isdigit(ultimate_array[m]))
            {
                c7--;m--;

                while(c7>=0)
                {
                    while(flag2==0)
                    {
                        c13=c7; flag2=1;
                    }
                    destination[t][c7]=ultimate_array[m];
                    c7--; m--;
                }
                break;
            }
        }

        for(n=c14;n<200;n++)
        {
            c11++; c14=c3+c13+c10;
            if(isupper(ultimate_array[n]))
            {
                c12=c11; c11=c11-1;
                while(c11>=0)
                {
                    fuel[t][c11]=ultimate_array[n];
                    c11--; n--;
                }
                break;
            }
        }

        c15=c14+c12;

        for(p=c15;p<200;p++)
        {
            c16++;
            if(ultimate_array[p]=='\n')
            {
                while(c16>=0)
                {
                    planetype[t][c16]=ultimate_array[p];
                    c16--; p--;
                }
                break;
            }
        }

        for(t1=0;t1<20;t1++)
        {
            printf(" %c",plane[t1][t]);
        }

        printf("\n");

        for(t2=0;t2<100;t2++)
        {
            printf("%c",destination[t2][t]);
        }

        printf("\n");

        for(t3=0;t3<100;t3++)
        {
            printf("%c",date[t3][t]);
        }

        printf("\n");

        for(t4=0;t4<100;t4++)
        {
            printf(" %c",fuel[t4][t]);
        }

        printf("\n");

        for(t5=0;t5<100;t5++)
        {
            printf(" %c",nflight[t5][t]);
        }
        printf("\n");
        for(t6=0;t6<5;t6++)
        {
            printf(" %c",planetype[t][t6]);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I have been struggling with a lot of things but I finally managed to separate every category to a different array, however , when I tried to do it for 2D array I always get garbage can someone point out what the mistake I did ?

we couldn't read in the input file and write it in a 2D array so the concept that i have used in this code i search in the array until i find something that would help me separate the word from the others such as 06281957 in the input i used isdigit to identify which index has it then i copy the previous characters into a new array this trick seemed to work for a 1d array however when i tried to scan it to 2d it stopped working and only random chars seemed to appeari wanted to print the whole 2d array of each category but i failed to do so, for the variables i used them as checkpoints for the next check to put the things i want in a new array. For minimizing the code i cant seem to find another solution to do so i know that my code is very big but if someone has a better idea it would be awesome.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also please read [this SO question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: "I always get garbage" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Comment: Can you provide a *precise* specification of what it is that you want to happen, including any and all rules, exceptions from those rules, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases? Can you provide sample inputs and outputs demonstrating what you expect to happen, both in normal cases, and in all the exceptions, corner cases, special cases, boundary cases, and edge cases?

Comment: Please, also make sure to provide a [mcve]. In particular, your example seems to be lacking at the "minimal" part of that. Are you really, absolutely, 100% sure that you cannot possibly demonstrate this problem in less than 146 lines? Additionally, the logic of your code is very hard to follow, in particular, the variable names are not very helpful in understanding the code and neither is the indentation. Lastly, it would help if you could tell us what you already did to try and debug the code, so that we don't needlessly duplicate the effort.

Comment: Ugh, that's, errr, interesting code. Look at [`scanf` with fixed-width specifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34759398/1270789) to simplify a lot of the code, or perhaps better, see if you can get the input in a more friendly format like JSON.

Comment: Hello sorry i didn't clarify my problem enough, so the problem is that we couldn't read in the input file and write it in a 2D array so the concept that i have used in this code i search in the array until i find something that would help me separate the word from the others such as 06281957 in the input i used isdigit to identify which index has it then i copy the previous characters into a new array this trick seemed to work for a 1d array however when i tried to scan it to 2d it stopped working and only random chars seemed to appear

Comment: i wanted to print the whole 2d array of each category but i failed to do so,  for the variables i used them as checkpoints for the next check to put the things i want in a new array. For minimizing the code i cant seem to find another solution to do so i know that my code is very big but if someone has a better idea it would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that will simplify your code is using [scansets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11632143/scanset-behaviour-in-scanf-in-c). It will make it much easier to extract and separate digits from non-digits, lower from upper case. [Fixed width specifiers](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) is also a concept you should read into. To see how many characters where extracted, use `%n` described in previous link. Examples:

```
  /* ... */
  inp=fopen("input.txt","r");
  /* your code... */
  for(i=0;!feof(inp);i++)
  {
    fscanf(inp,"%c",&ultimate_array[i]);
  }
  s=strlen(ultimate_array);
  for(i=0;i<s;i++)
  {
    printf("%c",ultimate_array[i]);
  }

  /* ...can be replaced by something similar to this (untested) */
  fscanf(inp, "%599s%n", ultimate_array, &s); /* read up to 599 characters, put number of read characters in s */
  ultimate_array[s]=0; /* set null terminator */
  char a[10]; sprintf(a, "%%%ds", s); /* create print format, e.g. "%123s" */
  printf(a, ultimate_array) /* print 's' number of characters */
```

Make sure to take it slow as the lines can be hard to read initially. As you become more familiar with it I'm sure you will find `scanf` does "exactly what is needed" using no loops or conditions at all.

Don't use `feof`. Instead check the return value from `scanf`. If you try extract a single "something" from file using `scanf` and it returns 0 (zero arguments were filled), you are done reading the file.

Making 2D arrays is *almost* always wrong. Group your variables in structures:

```
typedef struct flights_t {
  char plane[100];
  char date[100];
  /* ... */
} flights[6]; unsigned int nrOfFlights = 0;

int c[16];
int t[7];
```

Make symbolic constants instead of litering the code with copies of `20`, `100` and `6` all over for improved readability and maintainance. You will also recieve much better help from forums such as SO.

Your posted code is sadly beyond saving without proper description of what each code section is supposed to do. Hopefully this "answer" will get you going making better code.